# Remove everything after and including a tab in FASTA header?

Tags: sed, bioinformatics, fasta

I am trying to keep only the first field identifier for each sequence in a .fasta file that looks like this:

```
>hetGla3    ENST00000215754.179
ATGCCGATGTTCGTCTTGAACACCAACGTGCCCCGCGCCTCTGTGCCGGACGGGTTCCTCTCCGAGCTCACCCAGCAGCTGGCGCAGGCCACTGGCAAGCCGGCCCAGTATATCGCAGTGCACGTGGTCCCGGACCAGCTCATGACCTTCGCGGGCTCATCCGAGCCCTGCGCGCTCTGCAGCCTGCACAGCATCGGCAAGATAGGCGGCGTTCAGAATCGCTCGTACAGCAAGCTGCTGTGTGGCCTGCTGGCGGAGCGCCTGCGTATCAGTCCGGACAGGATCTACATCAACTACTACGACATGAATGCGGCCAATGTGGGCTGGAACGGCTCCACCTTCGCTNNN
>musMus10   ENST00000215754.270
ATGCCTATGTTCATCGTGAACACCAATGTTCCCCGCGCCTCCGTGCCAGAGGGGTTTCTGTCGGAGCTCACCCAGCAGCTGGCGCAGGCCACCGGCAAGCCCGCACAGTACATCGCAGTGCACGTGGTCCCGGACCAGCTCATGACTTTTAGCGGCACGAACGATCCCTGCGCCCTCTGCAGCCTGCACAGCATCGGCAAGATCGGTGGTGCCCAGAACCGCAACTACAGTAAGCTGCTGTGTGGCCTGCTGTCCGATCGCCTGCACATCAGCCCGGACCGGGTCTACATCAACTATTACGACATGAACGCTGCCAACGTGGGCTGGAACGGTTCCACCTTCGCTNNN
```

I want to remove the \tab and "ENST..." identifier after it, returning:

```
>hetGla3
ATGCCGATGTTCGTCTTGAACACCAACGTGCCCCGCGCCTCTGTGCCGGACGGGTTCCTCTCCGAGCTCACCCAGCAGCTGGCGCAGGCCACTGGCAAGCCGGCCCAGTATATCGCAGTGCACGTGGTCCCGGACCAGCTCATGACCTTCGCGGGCTCATCCGAGCCCTGCGCGCTCTGCAGCCTGCACAGCATCGGCAAGATAGGCGGCGTTCAGAATCGCTCGTACAGCAAGCTGCTGTGTGGCCTGCTGGCGGAGCGCCTGCGTATCAGTCCGGACAGGATCTACATCAACTACTACGACATGAATGCGGCCAATGTGGGCTGGAACGGCTCCACCTTCGCTNNN
>musMus10
ATGCCTATGTTCATCGTGAACACCAATGTTCCCCGCGCCTCCGTGCCAGAGGGGTTTCTGTCGGAGCTCACCCAGCAGCTGGCGCAGGCCACCGGCAAGCCCGCACAGTACATCGCAGTGCACGTGGTCCCGGACCAGCTCATGACTTTTAGCGGCACGAACGATCCCTGCGCCCTCTGCAGCCTGCACAGCATCGGCAAGATCGGTGGTGCCCAGAACCGCAACTACAGTAAGCTGCTGTGTGGCCTGCTGTCCGATCGCCTGCACATCAGCCCGGACCGGGTCTACATCAACTATTACGACATGAACGCTGCCAACGTGGGCTGGAACGGTTCCACCTTCGCTNNN
```

I have already tried sed to remove all whitespaces from headers, but it doesn't appear to be working (returns the original format):

```
sed 's/\.[^\.]*//'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using GNU `sed`

```
$ sed -E '/^>/s/( +|\t).*//' input_file
>hetGla3
ATGCCGATGTTCGTCTTGAACACCAACGTGCCCCGCGCCTCTGTGCCGGACGGGTTCCTCTCCGAGCTCACCCAGCAGCTGGCGCAGGCCACTGGCAAGCCGGCCCAGTATATCGCAGTGCACGTGGTCCCGGACCAGCTCATGACCTTCGCGGGCTCATCCGAGCCCTGCGCGCTCTGCAGCCTGCACAGCATCGGCAAGATAGGCGGCGTTCAGAATCGCTCGTACAGCAAGCTGCTGTGTGGCCTGCTGGCGGAGCGCCTGCGTATCAGTCCGGACAGGATCTACATCAACTACTACGACATGAATGCGGCCAATGTGGGCTGGAACGGCTCCACCTTCGCTNNN
>musMus10
ATGCCTATGTTCATCGTGAACACCAATGTTCCCCGCGCCTCCGTGCCAGAGGGGTTTCTGTCGGAGCTCACCCAGCAGCTGGCGCAGGCCACCGGCAAGCCCGCACAGTACATCGCAGTGCACGTGGTCCCGGACCAGCTCATGACTTTTAGCGGCACGAACGATCCCTGCGCCCTCTGCAGCCTGCACAGCATCGGCAAGATCGGTGGTGCCCAGAACCGCAACTACAGTAAGCTGCTGTGTGGCCTGCTGTCCGATCGCCTGCACATCAGCCCGGACCGGGTCTACATCAACTATTACGACATGAACGCTGCCAACGTGGGCTGGAACGGTTCCACCTTCGCTNNN
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option could be capturing the first part without spaces in group 1 and match the rest of the line that should be removed.

In the replacement use capture group 1 using `\1`

```
sed -E 's/^(>[^[:space:]]+)[[:space:]].*/\1/' file
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `(>[^[:space:]]+)` Capture group 1, match `>` and 1+ non spaces using a negated character class
- `[[:space:]]` Match a single space
- `.*` Match the rest of the line

Output

```
>hetGla3
ATGCCGATGTTCGTCTTGAACACCAACGTGCCCCGCGCCTCTGTGCCGGACGGGTTCCTCTCCGAGCTCACCCAGCAGCTGGCGCAGGCCACTGGCAAGCCGGCCCAGTATATCGCAGTGCACGTGGTCCCGGACCAGCTCATGACCTTCGCGGGCTCATCCGAGCCCTGCGCGCTCTGCAGCCTGCACAGCATCGGCAAGATAGGCGGCGTTCAGAATCGCTCGTACAGCAAGCTGCTGTGTGGCCTGCTGGCGGAGCGCCTGCGTATCAGTCCGGACAGGATCTACATCAACTACTACGACATGAATGCGGCCAATGTGGGCTGGAACGGCTCCACCTTCGCTNNN
>musMus10
ATGCCTATGTTCATCGTGAACACCAATGTTCCCCGCGCCTCCGTGCCAGAGGGGTTTCTGTCGGAGCTCACCCAGCAGCTGGCGCAGGCCACCGGCAAGCCCGCACAGTACATCGCAGTGCACGTGGTCCCGGACCAGCTCATGACTTTTAGCGGCACGAACGATCCCTGCGCCCTCTGCAGCCTGCACAGCATCGGCAAGATCGGTGGTGCCCAGAACCGCAACTACAGTAAGCTGCTGTGTGGCCTGCTGTCCGATCGCCTGCACATCAGCCCGGACCGGGTCTACATCAACTATTACGACATGAACGCTGCCAACGTGGGCTGGAACGGTTCCACCTTCGCTNNN
```

---

If `awk` is also an option, you can print field 1 if the line starts with `>`, else you print the whole line.

```
awk '/^>/ {print $1;next}1' file
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the job that `cut` exists to do:

```
$ cut -f1 file
>hetGla3
ATGCCGATGTTCGTCTTGAACACCAACGTGCCCCGCGCCTCTGTGCCGGACGGGTTCCTCTCCGAGCTCACCCAGCAGCTGGCGCAGGCCACTGGCAAGCCGGCCCAGTATATCGCAGTGCACGTGGTCCCGGACCAGCTCATGACCTTCGCGGGCTCATCCGAGCCCTGCGCGCTCTGCAGCCTGCACAGCATCGGCAAGATAGGCGGCGTTCAGAATCGCTCGTACAGCAAGCTGCTGTGTGGCCTGCTGGCGGAGCGCCTGCGTATCAGTCCGGACAGGATCTACATCAACTACTACGACATGAATGCGGCCAATGTGGGCTGGAACGGCTCCACCTTCGCTNNN
>musMus10
ATGCCTATGTTCATCGTGAACACCAATGTTCCCCGCGCCTCCGTGCCAGAGGGGTTTCTGTCGGAGCTCACCCAGCAGCTGGCGCAGGCCACCGGCAAGCCCGCACAGTACATCGCAGTGCACGTGGTCCCGGACCAGCTCATGACTTTTAGCGGCACGAACGATCCCTGCGCCCTCTGCAGCCTGCACAGCATCGGCAAGATCGGTGGTGCCCAGAACCGCAACTACAGTAAGCTGCTGTGTGGCCTGCTGTCCGATCGCCTGCACATCAGCCCGGACCGGGTCTACATCAACTATTACGACATGAACGCTGCCAACGTGGGCTGGAACGGTTCCACCTTCGCTNNN
```